# Animate a path using Leaflet and D3.js

Tags: animation, d3.js, routes, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am trying to implement the following example to animate a path using Leaflet and D3.js: http://zevross.com/blog/2014/09/30/use-the-amazing-d3-library-to-animate-a-path-on-a-leaflet-map/.

I receive an error in line 110 saying that d is undefined and I can't find a solution. Any idea on how to solve it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ=="
     crossorigin=""/>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw=="
      crossorigin=""></script>
  <style>
      html,
       body {
           height: 100%;
           width: 100%;
       }
       body {
           margin: 0;
       }
      #map {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
      } 
  </style>     
 </head>
     
 <body>
 
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">      

    // set up the map
    map = new L.Map('map');

    // create the tile layer with correct attribution
    var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osmAttrib='Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
    var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 15, attribution: osmAttrib});  

    // start the map in Donosti
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(40.72332345541449, -73.99),14);
    map.addLayer(osm);
 

    var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg");

    var g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");


    d3.json("points.geojson", function(collection) {

        var featuresdata = collection.features.filter(function(d) {
            return d.properties.id == "route1"
        });



        var transform = d3.geo.transform({
            point: projectPoint
        });

        var d3path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

        var toLine = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("linear")
            .x(function(d) {
                return applyLatLngToLayer(d).x
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return applyLatLngToLayer(d).y
            });

        var ptFeatures = g.selectAll("circle")
            .data(featuresdata)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 3)
            .attr("class", "waypoints");

        var linePath = g.selectAll(".lineConnect")
            .data([featuresdata])
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "lineConnect");

        // This will be our traveling circle it will
        // travel along our path
        var marker = g.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("id", "marker")
            .attr("class", "travelMarker");
   
        var originANDdestination = [featuresdata[0], featuresdata[17]];

        var begend = g.selectAll(".drinks")
            .data(originANDdestination)
            .enter()
            .append("circle", ".drinks")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .style("fill", "red")
            .style("opacity", "1");

        // I want names for my coffee and beer
        var text = g.selectAll("text")
            .data(originANDdestination)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.properties.name
            })
            .attr("class", "locnames")
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return -10
            });


        // when the user zooms in or out you need to reset
        // the view
        map.on("viewreset", reset);

        // this puts stuff on the map! 
        reset();
        transition();

        // Reposition the SVG to cover the features.
        function reset() {
            var bounds = d3path.bounds(collection),
                topLeft = bounds[0],
                bottomRight = bounds[1];

            text.attr("transform",
                function(d) {
                    return "translate(" +
                        applyLatLngToLayer(d).x + "," +
                        applyLatLngToLayer(d).y + ")";
                });


            // for the points we need to convert from latlong
            // to map units
            begend.attr("transform",
                function(d) {
                    return "translate(" +
                        applyLatLngToLayer(d).x + "," +
                        applyLatLngToLayer(d).y + ")";
                });

            ptFeatures.attr("transform",
                function(d) {
                    return "translate(" +
                        applyLatLngToLayer(d).x + "," +
                        applyLatLngToLayer(d).y + ")";
                });

            // again, not best practice, but I'm harding coding
            // the starting point

            marker.attr("transform",
                function() {
                    var y = featuresdata[0].geometry.coordinates[1]
                    var x = featuresdata[0].geometry.coordinates[0]
                    return "translate(" +
                        map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x)).x + "," +
                        map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x)).y + ")";
                });


            // Setting the size and location of the overall SVG container
            svg.attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0] + 120)
                .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1] + 120)
                .style("left", topLeft[0] - 50 + "px")
                .style("top", topLeft[1] - 50 + "px");


            // linePath.attr("d", d3path);
            linePath.attr("d", toLine)
            // ptPath.attr("d", d3path);
            g.attr("transform", "translate(" + (-topLeft[0] + 50) + "," + (-topLeft[1] + 50) + ")");

        }; // end reset

        function transition() {
            linePath.transition()
                .duration(7500)
                .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)
                .each("end", function() {
                    d3.select(this).call(transition);// infinite loop
                }); 
        }; //end transition

        // this function feeds the attrTween operator above with the 
        // stroke and dash lengths
        function tweenDash() {
            return function(t) {
                //total length of path (single value)
                var l = linePath.node().getTotalLength(); 
            

                interpolate = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
                //t is fraction of time 0-1 since transition began
                var marker = d3.select("#marker");
                
                // p is the point on the line (coordinates) at a given length
                // along the line. In this case if l=50 and we're midway through
                // the time then this would 25.
                var p = linePath.node().getPointAtLength(t * l);

                //Move the marker to that point
                marker.attr("transform", "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")"); //move marker
                console.log(interpolate(t))
                return interpolate(t);
            }
        }; //end tweenDash


        function projectPoint(x, y) {
            var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
            this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
        }; //end projectPoint
    });

    function applyLatLngToLayer(d) {
        var y = d.geometry.coordinates[1]
        var x = d.geometry.coordinates[0]
        return map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x))


    };
  </script>
 </body>

</html>
```

And the external file needed to run the code is:

```html
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature",
 "properties": { "latitude": 40.722390, "longitude": -73.995170, "time": 1, "id": "route1", "name":"Gimme" },
 "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.99517, 40.72239 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature",
 "properties": { "latitude": 40.721580, "longitude": -73.995480, "time": 2, "id": "route1", "name":"Along route"  }, 
 "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.99548, 40.72158 ] } }]}
```

Comment: It's impossible to help you since you didn't post any code...

Comment: I have now posted the code, but is the same one explained in the link attached.

Comment: A bit unrelated: you can get the same animation effect with https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim/ , removing the need of using D3.

Comment: Your code is not a reproducible example. [Trying to run it](https://plnkr.co/edit/7SagqHVPpPrDAndLnXgk?p=preview) results in a `collection is undefined` error.

Comment: I guess it is because the data is in an external data file 'points.json' that I have taken from the link posted. I have also inserted the code of it now.